# Mapkit SwiftUI MKPolygon border color

Tags: swiftui, mapkit, stroke, mkpolygon

I am wirting an app for iOS 17 to check out the new and improved MapKit support in SwiftUI.
So far, I have managed to draw MKPolygons and give them Polygons a Fill color, by using:

```
    MapPolygon(polygon)
       .foregroundStyle(properties.type.color.opacity(0.2))
```

However, I would (also) like to give the MKPolygon a border color.
In MapKit in UIKit, this was done by using the 'strokeColor' like so:

```
    let renderer = MKPolygonRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    renderer.lineWidth = 1
    renderer.fillColor = properties.type.color.withAlphaComponent(0.15)
    renderer.strokeColor = properties.type.color.withAlphaComponent(0.35)
    return renderer
```

I cannot find a way to give the MKPolygon a border(stroke) and a fill color in SwiftUI.

Comment: There is literally a method called `stroke`. Is that not what you want?

Comment: I know ... but:
It only has Linewidth as an argument, not color.
Or a ShapeStyle, and that has no color either.
So how can I give it a strokeColor?

Comment: `Color`s *are* a kind of `ShapeStyle`.

Comment: you could try `.stroke(.green, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 4))` or just `.stroke(.green, lineWidth: 4)`

Comment: That is it!

                                MapPolygon(polygon)
                                    .stroke(properties.type.color.opacity(0.4), lineWidth: 1)
                                    .foregroundStyle(properties.type.color.opacity(0.2))

Thanks Sweeper!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple overloads of [`stroke`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mapcontent/4232339-stroke) that you can use. You can pass in any [`ShapeStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shapestyle), a subset of which are `Color`s. Other `ShapeStyle`s include gradients (`.linearGradient(...)`) and materials (`.regularMaterial`).

```
MapPolygon(polygon)
    // assuming properties.type.color is of type Color
    .stroke(properties.type.color.opacity(0.35))
```